# FileUpload and Max length

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I am trying to solve a problem. I want to upload a file with the fileupload control with a max length of 10mb ( for example ). I maked all controls on the dimension of the file, but when i try to upload a file greater than 10mb the browser show me the "page fault" page.

There is a way to intercept the error by server side ?

thank you all

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        StatusLabel.Text = Server.MapPath("~/prova")
                         + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var section = config.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime")
                                     as HttpRuntimeSection;
        section.MaxRequestLength = 10485760*200;
    }

    HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/prova") + filename);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be"
                                 + " uploaded. The following error occured: "
                                 + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source,
                                               ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (FileUpload1.FileContent.Length < 10485760)
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by "I maked all controls on the dimension of the file," ???

Comment: Start by showing your code Curlyman..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the maxRequestLength.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="1200" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you want to intercept the exception regardless then you'll need to handle it in Global.asax. Here's a link to a 
[code example](http://geekswithblogs.net/sglima/archive/2011/09/20/how-to-handle-maximum-request-length-exceeded-exception.aspx)